# Programmatically adding event handler to array of radio buttons

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net-2010

Trying to add event handlers to radio buttons that are created on user input, looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760892/add-on-click-event-to-picturebox-vb-net) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743596.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) as examples.

However I get an error that `answerOptions` is not an event.

Create the radio buttons

```
Private answerOptions(n) As RadioButton
...    
Private Sub showQuestion(n As Integer)

For i = 0 To answerOptions.Length - 1
    answerOptions(i) = New RadioButton
    AddHandler answerOptions, AddressOf Me.Radios_Click
    With answerOptions(i)
        ' --------- SET TEXT, LOCATION ETC.
    End With
    Me.Controls.Add(answerOptions(i))
Next
End Sub
```

Planning on then handling events with

```
Private Sub Radios_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles answerOptions.checked

End Sub
```

I want things to happen when the radios are checked. Don't want to use checkboxes as I want to limit one selection at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your form or page

```
    Private Sub ClickButton(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim Rbtn As RadioButton
    Rbtn = CType(sender, RadioButton)
    MsgBox(Rbtn.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Rbtn As New RadioButton()

    For i = 0 To 19
        Rbtn = New RadioButton()
        With Rbtn
            .Name = "RBtn" & i
            .Text = .Name
            .Checked = False
            .Left = 20
            .Top = (i * 20)
            .Visible = True
            Me.Controls.Add(Rbtn)
            AddHandler Rbtn.Click, AddressOf ClickButton
        End With
    Next

End Sub
```