# How to write out button event without using WPF controls?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio, wpf-controls

I do not know how to specify in the title, this is in WPF visual basic. I want to know how do I write a code so that when a button is clicked, the tabcontrol selection will be = 1

Here is what I have in my MainWindow, RightWindowCommands:

```
 <Button Content="Information" Cursor="Hand" Click="InformationButton_OnClick"
                      ToolTip="View the information"
                      x:Name="InformationView"/>
```

However, I did not use the WPF tools' Button, as this is a GUI that I have to place the button at RightWindowCommands, I want to know how to come out with the code so that `InformationButton_OnClick` gives me `tabControl.SelectedIndex = 1`. Please guide me on writing this code out

Comment: Need help! I can only find solutions in C# but not VB! Im very new to this, please guide me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a nice example for onclick event handling a picture, you can change it to a number instead of picture.

```
`AddHandler pic.Click, AddressOf pic_Click'

Private Sub pic_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim pic As PictureBox = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)
    ' etc...
End Sub
```

Source : [add on click event to picturebox vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760892/add-on-click-event-to-picturebox-vb-net)